# How to get ajax detail page with parameters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, json

I didn't match detail from bwin web site with parameters.

I want to get the match detail : https://livebetting.bwin.com/tr/live#/**4027841**

Parameters : 4/20358/**4027841**/85468804/283678585

How can I get details by using a parameter ?

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you please be more elaborate? Show us what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string adres = "https://livebetting.bwin.com/tr/live#/4027841";

    WebRequest gelenIstek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);

    WebResponse gelenCevap;

    gelenCevap = gelenIstek.GetResponse();

    // CultureInfo tr = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
    StreamReader donenDeger = new StreamReader(gelenCevap.GetResponseStream());

    string gelenBilgi = donenDeger.ReadToEnd();

    int haberBaslangic = gelenBilgi.IndexOf("<ul class=\"leftCol\">") + 20;

    int haberBitis = gelenBilgi.Substring(haberBaslangic).IndexOf("<ul class=\"rightCol\">");

    string yazi_al = gelenBilgi.Substring(haberBaslangic, haberBitis);

    div.InnerHtml = yazi_al;
```

I can not print the source code : https://livebetting.bwin.com/tr/live#/4027841